# In the beginning of Gotham, why are the Waynes walking through the alley?

Tags: dc, batman, gotham

I have just watched the first episode of *Gotham* and am curious why, if the Waynes are extremely rich, they bother walking through a dark street instead of driving and taking an expensive car in front of the theatre? It's common sense that walking in the street like that would not be recommended especially for millionaires like them.

Comment: The show is terrible.

Comment: I know nothing of the show, but in general Batman, this is Canon.  They were leaving the theater early because Bruce was tired (exact reason I don't remember but it was Bruce who got them to leave) and since they didn't want to disturb the rest of the audience, they left through a side-door into the alleyway so as not ot disturb anyone else.

Comment: When you live in a beautiful city like Gotham, wouldn't you rather walk than take your silly old car with bullet-proof windows?

Comment: Celebrities like movie stars, sports figures, and musicians walk the streets of the cities they live in all the time.  Valleting your car to see a show can come off as a bit flashy and unnecessary.  Considering their relative altruistic popularity amongst the citizens of Gotham, they held a certain level of celebrity status that probably provided them with a feeling of safety most of the time.

Comment: @Zibbobz Can you confirm the reason? In fact, I want to know the reason that is told in the comic rather that the show. Well the editor edited my question to ask solely on the show so I accept the answer accordingly. (I could't help myself accept his edit cause he edited my grammar so nice.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When Bruce gives his account to Gordon, he says they were cutting through the alley to catch an uptown cab.

> We just got out of the movies.
>
> (sniffles) We were walking through the alley to catch an uptown cab,
>   and a man came out of the shadows.

Comment: This is the answer given in the pilot. Kind of silly if you ask me.

Comment: I know I spent the next minute or two wondering why they couldn't catch a cab right outside the theatre. One-way street going the wrong direction? For that matter, why the heck wasn't Alfred driving them? Just what do they pay him for, anyway?

Comment: Or just call an Uber, ferchrissakes....

Comment: @PatrickWynne Alfred is their butler, and not their driver. These are entirely different jobs.  And in fact in n DC continuity that i know have the Waynes ever been portrayed as having a driver.

Comment: I still curious about what is the reason it is told in the comic edition?

Comment: @gentlerainsky Then I highly encourage you to ask that question!  I think you have enough rep to link this question, but if not just reference that you previously asked specifically about the TV Show Gotham, and that you're curious about comic book continuity too.

Comment: @RBarryYoung In Batman: TAS and the Burton-verse, Alfred is often seen functioning as a chauffeur.