# In comic version of Batman, why are the Waynes walking through the alley?

Tags: dc, batman

The Waynes are extremely rich, why they don't drive their car out of the theatre instead of walking through a dark alley which is a common sense that a millionaire like them should not.

Note that I have just ask similar question for the TV Series version (Gotham) ([relate from my former question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68609/in-the-beginning-of-gotham-why-are-the-waynes-walking-through-the-alley)) , I just want to ask what is the reason that was provided in the comic version?

Comment: which comic version? There have been about twenty different versions of batman's origin story over the years.

Comment: Without rummaging through my modest collection of batman comics, in pretty much every version they're either looking to get to a cab quicker (because of the queue outside the theatre) or just walking home and taking a shortcut.

Comment: Well, I have not much knowledge about that, please provides any good one or more. (or suggest any version that I should edit my question into.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Batman's *original* origin story (Detective Comics #33 - 1939) the Wayne family were simply trying to get home by walking through the alleyway.

[image]

Comment: For the record, there's no mention of whether they were planning to walk *all* the way home to stately Wayne Manor